# Статические константные члены класса

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, static, const

Не компилируется код:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    static const double Val = 12.3;
};

int main()
{  
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

> 'Foo::Val': a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type or be specified as 'inline'

Компилировал в VS 2019 Community со стандартом c++17 и c++14. g++ выдает тоже самое. Насколько Я знаю, начиная с C++11 ограничение на не интегральные типы было снято. В чем проблема?

Comment: Это не интегральный тип, с `double`'ом так нельзя...

Comment: @Harry я имел ввиду, что теперь можно использовать не только интегральный тип. Спасибо  за правку. Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697265/static-const-double-cannot-have-an-in-class-initializer-why-is-it-so/36010468

Comment: можете написать constexpr вместо const и все будет работать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандарт С++17, 11.3.8.2.3.

> If a non-volatile non-inline const static data member **is of integral or enumeration type**, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression (7.7).

Так что - только интегральные типы.

Но вы можете написать

```
static constexpr double Val = 12.3;
```

или

```
static inline const double Val = 12.3;
```

и [все получится](https://ideone.com/jn8j4M).

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Я понял. Я могу задать значение в классе только для интегральных типов.  А в моем случае, Я должен написать после определения класса `const double Foo::Val = 12.3;`

Comment: Совершенно верно. Или дописать `inline`.

Comment: ...или `constexpr`, который автоматически добавляет `inline`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо, добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это, кстати, актуально, начиная с С++17 именно. Так что если опираться на метку вопроса не совсем подходит.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ До С++17 `constexpr` тоже подойдет, хотя будет работать хуже (`inline` не добавляет, потому что его нет; и похоже, что попытка взять адрес у такой переменной дает undefined reference). Плюс, глядя на сам вопрос, не уверен, что ТС правильный тег поставил.